# Is it possible to switch from screen to screen by just using one JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

Is it possible to switch from screen to screen by just using one `JFrame`?
Do i need to create another `JFrame` or use `JPanel`s and turn it on/off on button presses to create an illusion of jumping from screen to screen?
Or is there any other more efficient way to do this with other containers like
`JDesktopPane`, `JLayeredPane`, `JInternalFrame` and etc in netbeans ide?
What is the purpose and difference in usage of Swing Containers & Swing Windows?
When to use Containers and when to use windows?
By the way, i'm trying to build an Inventory System App Interface.

Comment: An application should have a single JFrame. That is the global master window that houses everything. If you want to have warning popups/dialogue boxes, then these should be modal and thus take focus away from the main window. What are thinking/talking about is context switching within the window. Whether you have all the panels loaded and change whether or not they're rendered, or load them as required will be based on user experience. But there's no technical reason that either solution should be chosen over the other.

Comment: @DanTemple, I doubt that majority will agree with you. I can give you a lot of well known applications that create several independent windows. For example IntelliJ creates separate window for each project you open (I mean ipr file).

Comment: which would you recommend? to create several independent windows for my app or manipulate panels through setVisible() inside a single window?

Comment: because i want to create an interface that updates the screen when you click on add product button -> labels and textfields will show up. And when you click the back button, it will return to the initial menu without popping out a dialog or changing the size or location of the window.

Answer (score 0):

you can use **JInternalFrame** which is make how many **child** **Frames** you want in a **JFrame** and you can do also **iconified**,**closable**,**resizable** ... by make them true in **child** **Frames** until you can use **JPanel** **instead of** **JFrame** and **switch** between them(child Frame's) by just **one click**!

**Edited------------**

For Example:

```
     JInternalFrame jInternalFrame = new JInternalFrame("Hello!",true,true,true,false);
     jInternalFrame.setSize(160,200);
     getContentPane().add(jInternalFrame);
     jInternalFrame.add(panel);
     jInternalFrame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: i think JInternalFrame needs to be contained inside a container before it can be used.

Comment: yes,you should add JInternalFrame to Current Container,not upside!

Comment: which method would you recommend? 
To create several JFrame for my Inventory System App or Just one JFrame and the rest are JInternalFrame.

Comment: My inventory app is going to be a menu with AddProduct, RemoveProduct, ShowProductList.

Comment: I was thinking maybe i can just use JPanels and turn the setVisible() of the specific panel on and off with ActionListener.

Comment: you have just one JFrame like orginal Frame and you can make JInternalFrame's in your orginal Frame!it's the easier for switching.

Comment: for menu's you should make MenuItem's and add all of them to a Menu and then add the Menu to a JMenuBar and in last step add JMenuBar to a JPanel(for example)

Comment: and for Frames you should don't use ActionListener!you can use WindowsListener.

Comment: Sorry, i mean a list of buttons : AddProduct Button, RemovePRoduct Button and ShowProductList Button. Then when you click on AddProduct Button, it's going to update the screen to some product info textfields.

Comment: I'm looking for the most efficient way to create the interface 
Should i use multiple JFrames? or One JFrame and the rest JInternalFrame? or One JFrame and the rest JPanel?
Which way?

Comment: `you should add JInternalFrame to Current Container` - a JInternalFrame should be added to a JDesktopPane.

Comment: you should add JInternalFrame to Current Container - a JInternalFrame should be added to a JDesktopPane in a JFrame or JPanel,tnx

Answer (score 0):

> And when you click the back button, it will return to the initial menu without popping out a dialog or changing the size or location of the window.

Sound like you can use a `CardLayout`. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Card Layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for more information and examples.